# Using AVPlayer/AVPlayerViewController with VLCKit / 3rd party libraries

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos

i am currently working on a media streaming app for tvOS (Apple TV 4th gen). I am using the VLCKit library to handle the video (mainly Matroska, which i don't think is natively supported in AVPlayer).
I managed to get the video streams working without any problems. Now i need controls for playback/pause, forward/rewind and more. The native controls offered in tvOS which are used in nearly every tvOS media-app right now are available through the AVPlayer/AVPlayerViewController classes.

The question is: Can i use those controls with VLCKit (or any other 3rd party library)? I already looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/) but i could not find a way to hookup the controls to custom code. I also don't quite understand if there is a way to set a custom view (my VLCKit playerView for example) "behind" the AVPlayer controls.

Maybe someone has used the native AVPlayer controls with a 3rd party library. Any hint in the right direction would help :)

Regards,

Timo

Comment: I did not. I ended up implementing my own Video controls.